# Cannot Parse Date and get Milliseconds

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a String into Date.

I am using

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("20140923-14:32:34.456")
```

My output is: (Date object)

```
Tue Sep 23 14:32:34 EDT 2014
```

I dont understand why I do not get the milliseconds. I need the date along with milliseconds and not just the milliseconds.

Expected Output: (Date object)

```
Tue Sep 23 14:32:34.456 EDT 2014
```

thanks

PS: I dont want a string object in the end but a Date.

Comment: How are you outputting it?  If you're just throwing a `Date` at the console, you're running its `toString()` method, which won't include the millis.

Comment: Just used System.out.println. So how do I get the entire dateobject including milliseconds

Comment: What time zone does your string represent? [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just printing out the result of calling `Date.toString()` which happens not to include the milliseconds. If you print out the result of calling `getTime()` on the date, you'll see that it ends in "456", showing that it *has* parsed the milliseconds.

Also, don't be fooled by the "EDT" part of the output of `Date.toString()`. It doesn't mean that this is a `Date` object "in" EDT... a `Date` doesn't have a time zone at all; it's just a number of milliseconds since the unix epoch.

I'd advise you to explicitly set the time zone of your `SimpleDateFormat`, however - even if you deliberately set it to the system default time zone. By doing it explicitly, you make it clear to the reader that you *meant* to use that time zone, rather than just that you failed to think about it. You should take the same approach to the locale, too - in this case I'd probably specify `Locale.US`, which is usually a good bet for formats which are designed more for machine-parsing than humans.

Comment: I want a date object with milliseconds. SO my expected output is Tue Sep 23 14:32:34.456 EDT 2014

Comment: All date objects have milliseconds.

Comment: @sa_nyc: Then you shouldn't call `Date.toString()`, because that's not going to give you that output.

Comment: @sa_nyc You confuse a date-time object with its String representation. In other words: ( `Date` ≠ `String`). The answer here by Jon Skeet is trying to explain that *you did indeed get the Date object you desired*, but are confused by the oddly-designed implementation of the `toString` method on that class where your JVM’s local time zone is applied on-the-fly while generating a String using an awkward format that happens to suppress milliseconds. Rather than typing more questions and comments, I suggest you slow down and search "java date" on StackOverflow for some enlightening study material.

Comment: Understood... Ya I checked the value of "cdate" in date object in my debug perspective. And I finally figured. Thanks all...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the format when printing the date you just read too:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS")
Date date = sdf.parse("20140923-14:32:34.456");
System.out.println(date);               // Tue Sep 23 14:32:34 EDT 2014
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));   // 20140923-14:32:34.456
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Date object does already contain the correct milliseconds. It's just that, when you are writing the Date object back out again, the default String representation of a Date does not include milliseconds.

You presumably have:

```
DateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date myDate = myFormat.parse("20140923-14:32:34.456");
```

To output the date with milliseconds, you should use:

```
System.out.println(myFormat.format(myDate));
```

Instead of reusing myFormat, you could use a different DateFormat that also includes milliseconds in its specification.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26026402/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

I will add some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

The java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome, flawed in both design and implementation. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

In both Joda-Time and java.time, a date-time object knows its own assigned [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), unlike in java.util.Date. Another difference is that both those good libraries use [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) where we instantiate fresh objects based on original object rather than alter ("mutate") the original.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.UTC; // Or DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" )
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS" ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("20140923-14:32:34.456"); // Parsed *and* assigned the specified time zone.
String output = dateTime.toString();
```

You can convert to another time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

If you really need a java.util.Date, perhaps required by other classes, convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```